# Простой редирект

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно перенаправить с `/view_pic?id=3758` на `/picture/3758`

Делаю так

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/view_pic
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*?)$
RewriteRule .* /picture/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Редирект в итоге идёт на /picture/?id=3758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/view_pic
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.+)$
RewriteRule .* /picture/%1? [L,R=301]
```

**P.S.** Подвыражения в регулярных выражениях (заключенные в скобки), доступны для вставки в [`СТРОКУ ПОДСТАНОВКИ`]. Обращаться к подвыражениям нужно так:

`%N` - для подвыражений в условиях (`RewriteCond`) и
`$N` - для подвыражений в правилах (`RewriteRule`),
где `N` - порядковый номер подвыражения.